# How can I modify how bars are displayed on a R barplot

Tags: r, graphics, bar-chart

I would like to plot 2 graphs of the same time serie, the first one would represent value, the second frequency of the same variable.

```
date   1  2  3  4  5  6  7 ...
value v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 ...
freq  f1 f2 f3             ...
```

The first graph is a usual `plot`, the second is a `graphics::barplot`, my problem is that I want the x-ticks to be on the same vertical line (after all it is the same date).
It seems that `barplot` is centering the bars so any vertical line representing date is shifted (zoom on the graph bellow to see what I mean)

How can I arrange this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it without using `barplot()`, but rather `plot()` with a different plot "type" argument.  And do make sure that your x-axis values are the same.

An old example of mine is the [Bollinger Bands plotting](http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/graph/Bollinger_Bands_65) at the R Graph Gallery.  It uses `segments()` for the volume bars.

Comment: Good idea Dirk, thanks though will I be able to have "thick" lines for the volume ?

Comment: Use the `lwd` argument as for all other plotting functions.